# CSS Shorthand methods for Display Flex and Flex Direction

Tags: css, sass

Is there a short hand method in CSS to combine

```
display:flex;
flex-direction: row / column?
```

into one line instead of two?

I know `flex-flow`, does `flex-direction and flex wrap.`

Comment: You could make a short hand method for this

Comment: There isn’t unfortunately. That’s due to the way the display property is supposed to behave. It predates flexbox and allowing it to take multiple values was never intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you are versed in Sass, however if you are, this is a quick way on how to make your idea work, you could also polish this further whith `@if` statements and `@error` directives, but here's the quick and easy way:

Here's a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/MrFuze/pen/KKzqdKM) to demonstrate.

The **mixin**:

```
@mixin fd($flex, $direction) {
  display: $flex;
  flex-direction: $direction;
}
```

This is how you **include** it:

```
@include fd([display], [direction]);

.flex-1 {
  @include fd(flex, row);
  // whatever goes next
}

.flex-2 {
  @include fd(inline-flex, column);
  // whatever goes next
}
```

This is what it **compiles** to:

```
.flex-1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.flex-2 {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```